# 単項プラス演算子の存在意味はなんでしょうか？

Tags: c

演算結果としてはなんの効果もないですよね。にもかかわらず存在する意味はなんでしょう。
強いて言えば、intやdoubleへの昇格する効果と単項マイナス演算子との対称性のためかもしれませんが
単項プラス演算子を使う必要性を感じた場面がありません。ある方がいらっしゃれば使い道をお教えください。

Comment: 参考:[What is the purpose of the unary plus (+) operator in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637005/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

標準化委員会がC言語仕様の理論的根拠(Rationale)をまとめた文書には「単項マイナス演算子との対称性のため」と記載があります。

https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf

> 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators
> Unary plus was adopted by the C89 Committee from several implementations, for symmetry with unary minus.

実際に K&R C 1st Ed. 時点では単項プラス演算子は存在しませんでした。

> 2.5 Arithmetic Operators
> [...] There is a unary `-`, but no unary `+`.

---

> 単項プラス演算子を使う必要性を感じた場面がありません。ある方がいらっしゃれば使い道をお教えください。

コンパイラにとっては、さほど強い意味はないと思います。
（厳密には単項プラス演算子によりpromotionが発生しますが、C言語の範疇で本挙動を有効に使うシーンがあるかといわれると微妙...）

プログラマ向けの情報としてはソースコードにて「数値の符号が正」を明確化し、意図を強調する効果があると思います。

Answer (score 5):

短い答え：単項 `+` が導入されたそもそもの根拠 (rationale) は、単項 `-` との対称性であるとは、コメントのリンク先に記載されています。なので「実用的に使えなくて一向にかまわない」ってことでしょう。

長い答え：
JIS X 3010:2003 ([c99](/questions/tagged/c99)) 6.5.3.3 単項算術演算子
JIS X 3014:2003 ([c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03)) 5.3.1 単項演算子
の解説によると既に指摘のある通りで、単項 `+` 演算子の機能は
- 汎整数昇格が行われる場合には昇格した後の型
- 結果は `rvalue` となる ([c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) には `prvalue` は未導入)
- [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) では 算術型 のみ許される (要するにポインタ型はダメ)
- [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03) では 算術型 だけでなくポインタ型も許される

あたりです。

これらの違いをソースコード上で小手先テクニックとして使うサンプルならいくつか思いつきますが、ではそれが実用的かとなるといささか疑問です。オイラが単項 `+` を積極的に使ったときは、ソースコード中に正負０の値が出現する定数テーブルの表を書いた時ですかね。エディタの長方形選択機能がうまく使えるように桁をそろえたい、かつ見た目を `0` とは明確に区別したい、場合くらいだと思います。

```
static int16 const mytable[]={
    -12, -10, - 8, + 4,   0,   0,   0,
    + 1, + 2, +11, - 1, - 2,   0,   0, 
      0,   0, + 3, + 6, + 8, +21, +20,
};
// +08 とか書くとハマるので注意！
```

単項 `-` だと、勝手に昇格後の型になってもらうと困る場合ってのがいっぱい思いつきますが単項 `+` ではそういうこともなし、使う必要性は無くてもいいんでしょう。

---

`atoi()` [man atoi](https://ja.manpages.org/atoi/3) や `strtol()` [man strtol](https://ja.manpages.org/strtol/3) あるいは [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) `std::stoi()` [cppref](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/string/stoi.html) は、変換元文字列中の `+` を受け付ける仕様なので、これに倣っているのかもしれないです（未調査）機械生成したテキスト形式データファイル（符号として `+` や `-` を含む形式）を Excel や C で作ったプログラムは受け付けるわけですが、そのデータファイルをそのまま [c](/questions/tagged/c) ヘッダファイルとして(別の)ソースコードに `#include` してコンパイルエラーになるってのはカッコ悪いっス。